# jQuery - Event that captures creation of dynamically created text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does jQuery have an event that will capture the creation of dynamically created DOM content? Or is there some way of doing this in jQuery?

The web page in which I am injecting jQuery into creates text boxes dynamically. I have no control over that. I would however like to check every 3 seconds whether a new text box has been created and then populate it with a value.

The text boxes look like the following:

```
<input id="AplEducationTbl:EstName:0" type="text" onchange="return false">
<input id="AplEducationTbl:EstName:1" type="text" onchange="return false">
```

So there are a couple of problems. The id uses a colon, which I don't know how to escape in jQuery. The onchange returns false, which prevents me from hooking on my events.

Using:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
      /* What do I put here? */
  }, 3000);
```

Comment: Have you tried with selector "input[tpye='text']" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I would however like to check every 3 seconds whether a new text box has been created*

To this you have to use `setInterval()` method instead:

```
var len = $('input[id^="AplEducationTbl:EstName"]').length;
setInterval(function () {
   if ($('input[id^="AplEducationTbl:EstName"]').length > len) {
      console.log('changed.');
      len = $('input[id^="AplEducationTbl:EstName"]').length; 
   }  //^^^^----------------------------------------update the value of len
}, 3000);
```

---

*The id uses a colon, which I don't know how to escape in jQuery.*

For this either you can use two forward slashes `\\` as suggested by other answer and other way to use a string representation put that id value in quotes like this:

```
$('input[id^="AplEducationTbl:EstName"]')
//-----------^-----------------------^------put the value in quotes like this 
//------------------------------------------and you are good to go.
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use event delegation and search for IDs starting with `AplEducationTbl:EstName`?

```
$(document).on("change", "input[id^=AplEducationTbl\\:EstName]", function() {
    console.log("Change");
});
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/jnM8n/)